# Adding code inside new created workbook sheet vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a button that will create a new workbook and save as new. Is it possible to automatically add a code inside the worksheet of the new created workbook? how?

for example I have event code. I want to apply on every workbook that will be created with no need to open the the new workbook and add the code manually. also I want the project to be protected.

is that possible in vba macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CreateWorkbookWithWorksheetProcedures()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim objVBProj As Object
    Dim objVBComp As Object
    Dim objCodeMod As Object
    Dim lLineNum As Long
    Dim sProcLines As String
' Create new workbook
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Add
    Set objVBProj = wbk.VBProject
    Set objVBComp = objVBProj.VBComponents("Sheet1")
    Set objCodeMod = objVBComp.CodeModule
' Add event procedure
    With objCodeMod
        lLineNum = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet")
        lLineNum = lLineNum + 1
        .InsertLines lLineNum, "    MsgBox ""Hello World"""
    End With
' Add common procedure
    lLineNum = objCodeMod.CountOfLines + 1
    sProcLines = "Sub HelloWorld()" & vbCrLf & _
        "    MsgBox ""Hello, World""" & vbCrLf & _
        "End Sub"
    objCodeMod.InsertLines lLineNum, sProcLines
' Save workbook
    wbk.SaveAs "c:\tmp\wbk.xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    wbk.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: how am I  going to add this on my code? my code was copying the sheet1 on the existing file then hide it, and add new sheet named "Request" then save as new, then under Request sheet I want to insert the `Private sub Worksheet_change()`

Comment: 1) Remove unnesessary code part (adding common procedure block); 2) Insert the proc code you need into a string variable (like in removed code part); 3) Replace string literal in .InsertLines with the variable; 4) Edit sheet name, add nesessary code for additional operations which you need in.